# Forma correta de executar query em Django?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, django

Preciso executa a query `SELECT pg_database_size('mydatabase')`, como faço isso em `Django` com o SGBD `Postgres`?

Já tentei fazendo o seguinte

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
size = cursor.execute('''SELECT pg_database_size("mydatabase")''')
```

Mas o resultando de `size` é `None`.

Como executo essa query? A intenção é retornar o tamanho do banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Na documentação oficial do django tem lá tutoriais a explicar como se faz e existem outros sites com tutoriais que voce pode aprender.

[Django tutoral](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/)

[Outros tutoriais](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/pt/django_orm/)